# This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type [ `Deprecated_use_float_module ]

Tags: ocaml

I am using Jane Streets Core library and I am trying to do a simple `float_of_int` operation. I am getting the following error

`This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type` 
`[ Deprecated_use_float_module ]`

How can I solve this? For instance, inside of the `utop` interpreter:

```
utop # open Core.Std;;
```

`utop # float_of_int 1;;
    Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type                                     [ Deprecated_use_float_module ]`

Thanks!

Edit: 
I also have looked inside the Float module [here](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core/#Std.Float) which seems to have nothing. Unless I just don't know how to navigate the documentation correctly, I am unsure of what to do.

Comment: it looks like that there is a bug on the doc site.  I usually, just open mli files from emacs and read comments there. If you're using opam, then you can find mli files in `.opam/<version>/lib/<library>`, where <version> stands for ocaml version, e.g., 4.01.0, and <library> is a library name, e.g., `core`

Comment: Thank you, your answer fixed my problem,  but I was more curious about the documentation issue. I'll refer to that from now on :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are trying to say to you, that you should use `Float.of_int` function. `float_of_int` function is deprecated by Janestreet Core library.